# How do I access Azure blob storage via a socks proxy?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I need to access, in Python, an Azure blob storage, but go through a Socks proxy (ssh DynamicForward).

Normally, I would do this:

```
client = azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient(url, credentials)
```

How do I make this client use a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Azure API uses `requests` to do it's HTTPS access. 
You can setup the requests session to use socks like this:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies["https"] = "socks5h://127.0.0.1:9876"
client = azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient(url, credentials, session=session)
```